# rescore spam corpus with rspamd

Tags: lua, rspamd

I recently tried to rescore my spam/ham corpus with [rspamds rescoring mechanism](https://rspamd.com/announce/2018/03/12/rspamd-1.7.0.html) (see the example in "Corpus test and rescore tool"), but unfortunately this ends in a runtime error. My current minimal test-case is the following:

1. `echo test > ~/test.txt`, generate dummy mail
2. `rspamadm corpus_test -o ~/minimal.log -s ~/test.txt`, generate a dummy log with one entry
3. `rspamadm rescore -l ~/minimal.log` produces a LUA runtime error

which always ends with the following LUA error:

`call to rspamadm lua script failed (2): /usr/share/rspamd/lib/nn/Linear.lua:25: bad argument #1 to 'size' (dimension 2 out of range of 1D tensor at /rspamd-1.7.4/contrib/torch/torch7/generic/Tensor.c:19); trace: [1]:{[C]:-1 - size [C]}; [2]:{/usr/share/rspamd/lib/nn/Linear.lua:25 - reset [Lua]}; [3]:{/usr/share/rspamd/lib/nn/Linear.lua:12 - __init [Lua]}; [4]:{/usr/share/rspamd/lib/torch/init.lua:91 - <unknown> [Lua]}; [5]:{[C]:-1 - Linear [C]}; [6]:{/usr/share/rspamd/lib/rspamadm/rescore.lua:530 - <unknown> [Lua]};`

When I run it with my actual corpus I get the same result. I have already reported the problem upstream but I still think that this might be an error on my side.